# high precision division in C

Tags: c, math, precision, floating-point-precision

I want to do the following calculation without losing precision in C.

```
uint64_t ts_1 = 0x5212cb03ca115ac0; 
uint64_t ts_2 = 0x5212cb03ca115cc0; 
uint64_t ts_delta = (ts_2 - ts_1)

double scale_factor = ts_delta/(2^32)
```

I am getting the value of ts_delta as `0x200.` However the value of scale_factor as `15.000000`.Basically I am losing precision during the calculation.

How do I do it without losing precision.?

Here is a short self contained example on how I am trying to print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
        uint64_t ts_1 = 0x5212cb03ca115ac0;
        uint64_t ts_2 = 0x5212cb03ca115cc0;
        uint64_t ts_delta = (ts_2 - ts_1);
        double scale_factor = ((double)ts_delta) / (((uint64_t)1) << 32);

        printf("ts_delta %"PRIx64" scale factor %f \n",ts_delta,scale_factor);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @PascalCuoq - see updated example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing the calculation you think you're doing.  The `^` operator in C does *not* perform exponentiation, it performs bitwise exclusive OR.  You are actually dividing `ts_delta` by `2 xor 32 == 34`.  I'm not sure how you got `15.000000` from that, it should have come out `15.058823529411764`.

The calculation you wanted to do is expressed in C like this:

```
double scale_factor = ((double)ts_delta) / (((uint64_t)1) << 32);
```

**EDIT:** From the other answer: if your compiler supports C99's hexadecimal floating-point literals, you can also write

```
double scale_factor = ts_delta * 0x1p-32;
```

Written this way, no casts are necessary, because one side of the multiplication is already a `double`, so the integer on the other side will be converted to match.  Unfortunately, several compilers have `uint64_t` but no other features of C99, e.g. recent MSVC.

Comment: I tried the above Now the scale factor I am getting is 0.000000

Comment: Please show *exactly* how you are printing out the value.  The number you should be getting is 1.1920928955078125e-07.

Comment: I have added an example demonstraing how I am printing the values.

Comment: Aha. Change `%f` to `%e` or `%g` or `%.9f`.  The number is small enough that it rounds to zero with the default precision for `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute floating point values, and get the expression for raising to a power right. You can use the standard function [`ldexp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp):

```
#include <math.h>

double scale_factor = ldexp(ts_2 - ts_1, -32)
```

Or just multiply by a constant (thanks @Eric Postpischil!):

```
double scale_factor = (ts_2 - ts_1) * 0x1p-32;
```

Comment: @liv2hak: It's a C standard library function... (e.g. [see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ldexp.3.html)).

Comment: Why use `ldexp` rather than multiplying by `0x1p-32`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks, that's a much saner idea! :-)